# How do I use the TarFile dereference flag in Python 2.4?

Tags: python, tar, python-2.x

I wrote a script that collects all our log files to one tar file. The problem is that it doesn't contain soft link's data. I tried to use the dereference flag but it is not recognized for python 2.4.3.

I can't use the command line since there's a length limit and I want to support many log files.

```
user ~/Desktop]$python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jun 11 2009, 14:09:37)

[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2

>>> import tarfile
>>> tarfile.TarFile('test.tar.gz', mode='w', dereference=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dereference'
>>>
```

Comment: Can't you use a more recent python version? 2.4 is quite old

Comment: I still don't get why you can't use command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Python 2.4 docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/lib/tarfile-objects.html) `dereference = True` is supported. It appears to have been supported since `tarfile` was added in Python 2.3.

Unless you're on a non-Posix system (Windows) you must be doing it wrong. Post your code and the error you get with `dereference = True` so we can tell you what that is.

Also, by soft links I assume you mean *symbolic* links? Because that's what `dereference = True` allows to work.

Edit: I just looked at the [code for tarfile on Python 2.4](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ceec209b26d4/Lib/tarfile.py#l777). It **does not support** the `dereference` parameter to the constructor, but it **does** seem to have the needed code to actually dereference (Checked against the [source for Python 2.6](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9f8771e09052/Lib/tarfile.py#l1472)). So,

```
import tarfile
tf = tarfile.TarFile('test.tar.gz', mode='w')
tf.dereference = True
```

should work. Please, update with your results.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the `-T` or `--files-from` option on `tar`?